# Need assistance with discord bot relay

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I've tinkered with creating my own discord bot and now I'm trying to work on making it relay from one discord to another.

The issue that I am having and I can't get answer for is this - the server I want to relay FROM i do not have access to add a bot to.

Has anyone attempted something similar to this and might have an idea on how one could accomplish this? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

The word "relay" means `receive and pass on (information or a message).` and you do not have access to add a bot to the server seems like you want to steal data from it. This is not allowed with discord and frowned upon.

You could try getting the owner of the server to invite it for you with the minimum amount of permissions necessary.

However, a self bot could work but may lead to a permanent ban of your account and is no longer supported in discord.py